# MAGENTO CONNECT ERROR: Package 'ASchroder_SMTPPro' is invalid './README.md' already exists'

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-connect, smtp

I am trying to install ASchroder_SMTPPro via Magento connect, but I keep getting the error:

> CONNECT ERROR: Package ' CONNECT ERROR: Package 'ASchroder_SMTPPro'
>   is invalid './README.md' already exists

I read online that the way to fix it would be to remove the file in question? How ever being a newbie I have no knowledge where does the connect installer files go? So I thought asking from here.

Could someone be so kind and tell me how to fix the error (do I delete the README.md)? and where is the right README.md located. I am using bitnami magento stack and doing a find search gives me too many results to know which one to delete.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the README.md from your root Magento folder. There is only one README.md in the Magento Connect package and it located in the root folder.
You will need FTP/SSH access to perform this, but simply removing that file should fix this issue for you.
If you continue having that error but with another file after removing the README, you will have to remove them all manually the same way you removed the README.md

Comment: Thank you, renaming the other readme help, but I still have naming conflict with composer.json on another extension, but I am dropping it. Thanks again

Comment: @ mbalparda : still, i get the error after remove README

Answer (score 0):

You have older version of SMTPPro already installed. Unfortunately Magento Connect doesn't allow overwriting, so you must uninstall pervious version first.

If you installed it manually, you must remove files of older version manually as well. I know that this is somewhat annoying, but ...

Comment: If I do have, it is not showing up at the
Manage Existing Extensions listing. What could cause that?

Comment: also I have not installed it previosly and it should show up as extension in the list right? I also did a find SMTPPro for the server, but it did not come up with anything

Comment: It's because the list shows only items you're installed using Connect, everything else doesn't appear there. Check if app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro or app/code/community/Aschroder/SMTPPro already exists and if yes, then there you are ...

Comment: Be aware there might be a lot of files if the extension is already installed, not only the README.md and the SMTPPro folder.

Comment: Jesus, do people ACTUALLY put stuff to root folder in their extensions?

Comment: You can ask Ashley, he is always around.

Comment: /spank Ashley :D